# How to check if length of four array is same ? Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to know if values of selected item same as number of input.
Example:

```
const objToSend = {
  name: this.form.value.name,
  description: this.form.value.description,
  durationInDays: this.form.value.durationInDays,
  mealsPerDay: this.form.value.mealsPerDay,
  recepieIds: [],
  breakfastIds: [],
  lunchIds: [],
  dinnerIds: [],
  snackIds: [],
}
this.arrOfRecipes.allRecipe.map(obj => { objToSend.recepieIds.push(obj.id) })
this.arrOfRecipes.breakfast.map(obj => { objToSend.breakfastIds.push(obj.id) })
this.arrOfRecipes.lounch.map(obj => { objToSend.lunchIds.push(obj.id) })
this.arrOfRecipes.dinner.map(obj => { objToSend.dinnerIds.push(obj.id) })
this.arrOfRecipes.snack.map(obj => { objToSend.snackIds.push(obj.id) })


if(objToSend.breakfastIds.length > 0 || objToSend.durationInDays > 0) { 
  if(objToSend.breakfastIds.length !== objToSend.durationInDays) {
    return alert('no same number')
  }
}
if(objToSend.lunchIds.length > 0 || objToSend.durationInDays > 0) {
  if(objToSend.lunchIds.length !== objToSend.durationInDays) {
    return alert('no same number')
  }
}
if(objToSend.dinnerIds.length > 0 || objToSend.durationInDays > 0) {
  if(objToSend.dinnerIds.length !== objToSend.durationInDays) {
    return alert('no same number')
  }
}
if(objToSend.snackIds.length > 0 || objToSend.durationInDays > 0) {
  if(objToSend.snackIds.length !== objToSend.durationInDays) {
    return alert('no same number')
  }
}

console.log('array of recipe', this.arrOfRecipes)
console.log('obj ', objToSend)
```

If the durationInDays is 5, some of these arrays must be 5.
If the durationInDays is 2, some of these arrays must be 2.

And also must be more then zero.

Comment: Define a property in this object, that will hold the keys of the arrays to be validated for length. Then write a method validateArrayLengths. Use a loop like `obj.arrays.forEach(a => { if(obj[a].length !== obj.durationInDays) { alert("length of" + a + "invalid") ;}) ;`

Answer (score -1):

I think you're overthinking it.

```
function isArrayLengthEqual(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4) {
    return (arr1.length == arr2.length && arr2.length == arr3.length && 
            arr3.length == arr4.length && arr4.length > 0)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know if all of the arrays are of length duration or just tell you which ones are?

Comment: No all, only one... But if two array selected example 2 items, durationInDays must be 2